# How to specify Windows credentials in WCF client configuration file

Tags: wcf, credentials

I have a WCF service using BasicHttpBinding with Windows authentication.
Most clients are domain accounts and connect to the service using their default credentials.

Now I want to connect to the service from an ASP.NET client that is running under a local account.  I want to connect to the WCF service using windows credentials (domain\user and password) that are available to the ASP.NET application.

I know I can do this in code using ClientBase<T>.ClientCredentials.

Is there a way to specify the credentials (domain\user and password) in the client's web.config file so I don't have to change the code?

**EDIT**

If it can't be done in the configuration file, is there a way of using System.Net.ICredentials or System.Net.NetworkCredential as a credential for a WCF service?

The .NET Framework provides these as a homogenous way to provide network credentials, but with WCF this seems to have been thrown out in favour of a new incompatible system based on the unrelated System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials class.

**EDIT 2**

Accepting Marc's answer to the original question - it seems there is no way to do this in the client configuration file :(

I would see this as a deficiency in WCF - I don't accept that Microsoft should be deliberately discouraging us from putting credentials in the configuration file - after all they have to be stored somewhere, and the Framework includes facilities for encrypting the config file.  I guess I could create a custom BehaviorExtensionElement for this, but it ought to be available out of the box.

It's also a bit inconsistent: the system.net/mailSettings/smtp/network configuration element allows credentials to be specified, so why not WCF?

Regarding the second question about using System.Net.NetworkCredential, it seems from [this blog](http://devdump.wordpress.com/tag/wcf/) that it is possible, at least when using Windows authentication, with the following code:

```
factory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential =
   new System.Net.NetworkCredential(name, password, domain);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't specify your credentials in the config file, unfortunately - you have to do this in code (most likely because otherwise you might end up with credentials in your config file, in plain text - not a good thing....).

Comment: "...in your config file, in plain text" is not generally a good thing, but in the config file encrypted is OK.

Comment: @marc_s Is it still not available to set via config file?

Comment: @Johnny_D: nope, not as far as I know.

Answer (score 19):

```
Svc.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = AppSettings["WCFSvcUsername"];
Svc.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = AppSettings["WCFSvcPassword"];
```

is incorrect. It is used with **message security** and **clientCredentialType="UserName"**. You should use

```
Svc.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential(...);
```

Comment: I did not your complete post. You have already know the answer of the question - sorry.

Comment: Although this is a very old question I post this for anyone with the same problem.

Comment: You also did not your complete sentence ;)

Answer (score 5):

It seems there is no way to set id and password in the default binding configuration (I'm still looking), I did it adding the code bellow, but still wish microsoft would add it to the default bindings

```
    <appSettings>
     <add key="user"  value="user" />
     <add key="password"  value="password" />
     <add key="domain"  value="domain" />
   </appSettings>


   // client side code
   string userName =  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("user");
   string pswd = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("password");
   string domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("domain");

   client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = domain; 
   client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = userName;
   client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = pswd;
```

Sebastian Castaldi

Answer (score 4):

I understand that there isn't a mechanism to specify the credentials within the <binding> tags, but why not do this:

```
 Svc.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = AppSettings["WCFSvcUsername"];
 Svc.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = AppSettings["WCFSvcPassword"];
```

Comment: that would work - but I'd strongly recommend encrypting your config file in this case!

Comment: Yes I know I can do it in code, I want to avoid changing the code.

Comment: Joe - my example would allow you to then specify your username and password in the app/web.config file as you can't do it natively.

Answer (score 2):

```
Svc.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = 
    System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
<system.web>
      <identity impersonate="true" userName="username" password="password"/>
</system.web>
```

Comment: No this doesn't really help - the ASP.NET server isn't trusted for delegation.